# Why can you only use Call By Name on class modules?

Tags: excel, vba, callbyname

I've encountered that in VBA for Excel you can only use CallByName on methods inside class modules, as this link indicates: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186143 .

My question is why that is? I don't see why the same functionality could not be used outside classes.

I'm not sure if this is a specific VBA question or if the same thing holds for other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Run` does the job for procedures in non-class modules ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx)).

Why doesn't `CallByName` work for non-class procedures? It's just not within the scope of that statement.